# Building a monad around Streaming & Reader

Tags: haskell, types, monad-transformers

I am trying to build a `Monad` instance of the following type:

```
data CmdY ρ η ω = CmdY (Reader ρ ((Stream (Of CmdSpec) η ω)))
```

where `Stream` and `Of` come from `Streaming` in the `streaming` package.

I have successfully written `Functor` `Applicative` instances:

```
instance (Monad η) => Functor (CmdY ρ η) where
  fmap :: (α -> β) -> CmdY ρ η α -> CmdY ρ η β
  fmap f (CmdY a) = CmdY $ (fmap f) <$> a

instance (Monad η) => Applicative (CmdY ρ η) where
  pure    = CmdY . pure . return

  (<*>) :: CmdY ρ η (α -> β) -> CmdY ρ η α -> CmdY ρ η β
  (CmdY f) <*> (CmdY a) = let ff = (<*>) <$> f
                           in CmdY $ ff <*> a
```

But I'm going round in circles trying to implement the bind `(>>=)` of the Monad.

I have a function to evaluate a CmdY and give me a stream & result:

```
runCmdY :: (MonadIO η, MonadIO μ, MonadReader (ProcExecCtxt μ) ψ) =>
           CmdY (ProcExecCtxt μ) η ω -> ψ (Stream (Of CmdSpec) η ω)
```

But given a bind of the form `a >>= f`, a is of type `CmdY (ProcExecCtxt η) η α` while f is of type `α -> CmdY (ProcExecCtxt η) η β`, I need to get something of type α to feed to my f, and I am failing to get there.

`ProcExecCtxt m` here is an execution context; it provides a means to evaluate cmds within the monad m.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious (or at least, I'm hoping it will be obvious once I see it); but I'd grateful for any pointers.

Thanks,

Comment: Please avoid complexity that's not relevant to the question (do you need `ProcExecCtxt` here?). Also add, references to what `Reader`, `Stream` and `Of` are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Reader ρ (Stream (Of CmdSpec) η ω)
```

is really just

```
 ρ -> Stream (Of CmdSpec) η ω
```

There's a third way to spell that type that probably makes more sense in this context:

```
ReaderT ρ (Stream (Of CmdSpec) η) ω
```

using `Control.Monad.Trans.Reader.ReaderT` (also exported by `Control.Monad.Reader`), a monad transformer defined

```
newtype ReaderT e m a = ReaderT
  { runReaderT :: e -> m a }
```

Since `ReaderT e` is a monad transformer, `ReaderT e m` is a monad whenever `m` is. Therefore, it will provide all the instances you want for free, and a couple more. Indeed, using

```
{-# language GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
```

you can write

```
newtype CmdY ρ η ω = CmdY
  { unCmdY :: ReaderT ρ (Stream (Of CmdSpec) η) ω }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad
           , Alternative, MonadPlus, MonadReader ρ)
```

Or, if you like, you can define the instances manually by wrapping and unwrapping `CmdY`:

```
instance Monad η => Functor (CmdY ρ η) where
  fmap f (CmdY m) = CmdY (fmap f m)

instance Monad η => Applicative (CmdY ρ η) where
  pure = CmdY . pure
  CmdY fs <*> CmdY xs = CmdY (fs <*> xs)

instance Monad η => Monad (CmdY ρ η) where
  CmdY m >>= f = CmdY $ m >>= unCmdY . f
```

`CmdY ρ` is itself a monad transformer:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class

instance MonadTrans (CmdY ρ) where
  lift = CmdY . lift . lift
```

Comment: uh, wow, and thank you.  So indeed, the use of ReaderT is the key here; I had actually started with a ReaderT, but removed it at one point as I felt it was adding complexity and obscuring what I needed to do.  I think I kindof understand now why that was wrong, but I'll need to stare at it for a bit.  Many thanks for the help, @dfeuer.

Comment: For the record, I needed to use `CmdY . lift . lift` to create the MonadTrans instance.

Comment: @user3416536, thanks for the correction. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @user3416536, one way to think about it: monads don't compose in general, so there's no *systematic* way to write a `Monad` instance for something like `Reader e . m`--we'd have to break open the `Reader` and work with its guts. Monad transformers, however, *do* compose in general, so we can systematically write a `Monad` instance for `(ReaderT e . Stream f) m` with no need to dig into the detailed mechanics of either transformer.

Answer (score 0):

[`Data.Functor.Compose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html) implements your `Functor` and `Applicative` instances.

[`ReaderT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html) implements a `Monad` instance for you.